# What action to use for when a post is saved / published, with a caveat

Tags: save-post, scheduled-posts

I'm trying to do some stuff when a post has been saved, I'm currently using the `save_post` action, of which generally works.

However, the problem I'm having is when a post is scheduled it fires the `save_post` action, of which changes some data I don't want it to.

Is there an action of which fires **only** when the user clicks publish / save in the post edit screen, and **not** when a post changes schedule status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check `if ( defined( 'DOING_CRON' ) && DOING_CRON )`, which will be true if the post save is triggered during a scheduled cron job.

Comment: Much better... ;)

Comment: Ah, good effort. Figures that this would be triggered from a CRON, thanks for this solution. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, so I've sorted this out myself.

I'm not using a different action, however as my functionality is based on Advanced Custom Fields, I've added a condition to only execute certain parts of my code when the `$_POST['fields']` variable exists.

Now scheduled posts don't mess my custom data when they go live.